# JSON Syntax Data Formatting

Tags: json, api, syntax, stocks

I am wondering if the attached image that represents how JSON data is returned from a stock market API is improperly formatted JSON data.
Here is a link to the API call that the image pictorially represents: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=A,AAPL&types=chart&range=1d

The API call essentiall returns market data for 1 day of both stock symbol A and AAPL (as an example). However, I thought JSON is typically [{}, {}, {}] or {[{}, {}]} format but this API batch request is {{[{}, {}]}}.

Would be much appreciated is someone could provide some insight.

[image: API call syntax markup]

Comment: See http://www.json.org/ for the proper JSON syntax and what it allows. The posted one is valid (*also note that if it was invalid your browser would not render it*).

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at that now